# How to avoid the .searchable from appearing and disappearing?

Tags: swiftui, searchable

I am having a lot of buggy behavior on `.searchable`, on iOS 16.1 (Xcode 14.1). As you can see in the screenshot below. When entering a view with a `.searchable` component it will overlap with the view in transition and then disappears.

[image]

I am trying to make the code as basic as possible.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink {
                    Mailbox().navigationTitle("Inkomend")
                } label: { Label("Inkomend", systemImage: "tray") }
                NavigationLink {
                    Mailbox().navigationTitle("Verstuurd")
                } label: { Label("Verstuurd", systemImage: "paperplane") }
                NavigationLink {
                    Mailbox().navigationTitle("Prullenmand")
                } label: { Label("Prullenmand", systemImage: "trash") }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Postbussen")
            .refreshable {}
        }
    }
}

struct Mailbox: View {
    @State private var searchQuery: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink {
                Text("Detail")
            } label: {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Apple").font(.headline)
                    Text("Verify your account.")
                    Text("Fijn dat je deze belangrijke stap neemt om je account te verifiëren.").lineLimit(2).foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchQuery)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've been dealing with the same problem with the NavigationStack. The `.searchable()` modifier should not be on the List but the NavigationStack. Alternatively put it on anything other than the List to have it appear in the child view.

Comment: You can cheat it with an empty view as such: `EmptyView().searchable(text: $searchText).listRowBackground(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))`. Put this in the child view instead of adding the `searchable` modifier to the List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Latin Bhuva said, the new NavigationStack is not intended to be used in this way, a NavigationView would be more correct in this case.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            NavigationLink {
                Mailbox().navigationTitle("Inkomend")
            } label: { Label("Inkomend", systemImage: "tray") }
            NavigationLink {
                Mailbox().navigationTitle("Verstuurd")
            } label: { Label("Verstuurd", systemImage: "paperplane") }
            NavigationLink {
                Mailbox().navigationTitle("Prullenmand")
            } label: { Label("Prullenmand", systemImage: "trash") }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Postbussen")
        .refreshable {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought NavigationView would be deprecated in favor of NavigationStack. it feels like such basic navigation that i wonder what navigationstack would be used for then.

Answer (score 1):

Use NavigationView instead of NavigationStack.

Answer (score 1):

In my case all I had to do is add placement to the searchable and it works fine with the NavigationStack:

```
 .searchable(
      text: $viewModel.searchText,
      placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always)
        )
```

Comment: I always wonder how people find this. Swiftui is scary sometimes ! Thank you anyway. It worked for me too!